# Is parseNetworkResponse method is called in UI thread

Tags: android, networking, android-volley

If you want write you own request object using volley, you must override parseNetworkResponse method. In this method you parse response and call static method Response.error or Response.success So my question:Is method called on separate thread or ui thread ? If I have big data to parse is good place to do this and return my object from request ?

Comment: have you tried ? by putting it on ui thread and have observed whether it gives you NetworkOnMainThreadException ?

Answer (score 2):

Volley calls **parseNetworkResponse()** from a worker thread. This ensures that expensive parsing operations, such as decoding a JPEG into a Bitmap, don't block the UI thread.

*Now What is worker thread ?*

**Ans :**
The **UI thread** makes changes required for the UI.

A **worker thread** is just another thread where you can do processing that you dont want to interupt any changes happening on the ui thread.
If you are doing large amounts of processing on the ui thread while a change to the ui is happening the ui will freeze until what ever you have running complete.

Reference : https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html